# Why is there no dscanf()?

Tags: c, linux, posix, scanf

Why is there no dscanf function for reading from file descriptors?

We have fprintf, sprintf and dprintf for printing but for scanning there is only fscanf and sscanf.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. But i guess I still have the same question, is there a reason they didn't also include dscanf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to write `dscanf`.

The scanf family requires that the stream is buffered, or else that it is capable of putting back a character that was read. POSIX file descriptors are neither.

Consider this stream

```
1234xyz
```

How would you scan a number off it? You cannot read it byte by byte and stop just before `x`. That would require clairvoyance. You also cannot read `x` and decide you don't need it, because you cannot put it back.

Comment: So no `dungetc()` either.  Just as well, function name looks "unattractive".

Comment: Why can't you seek to the previous position in the file?

Comment: @Autodidact Why can't you seek to the previous position in the terminal or in the socket?

Comment: @Autodidact It's possible in a file, but not all descriptors refers to files. As mentioned, there are also sockets and terminals, as well as pipes and serial ports and many other one-way modes of communication.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `printf` and `scanf` family of functions is part of the C language, the functions handling file descriptors are not. Instead they are part of the operating system API (on POSIX platforms like Linux or OSX, other platforms emulate these system calls).

And the `dprintf` function is *not* a standard C function, it's an extension. From [this `printf` (and family) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dprintf.3.html):

> The `dprintf()` and `vdprintf()` functions were originally GNU extensions that were later standardized in POSIX.1-2008.

That there's no `dscanf` function is probably just an oversight from those who made the original `dprintf` extension.

Comment: > just an oversight

yup